# How indexes are an overhead on insert/update/delete of a table?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

It is said that indexes increase retrieval speed for rows of a table, but they are overhead on insert/update/delete. I wanted to know how indexes become an overhead in terms of index architecture ? [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/766bb3cf-28ae-449b-ab8a-9d8ea9152a97/what-is-the-overhead-of-indexes?forum=transactsql) link isn't clear to me - I get mixed up between clustered and non-clustered indexes.

Comment: Simply put, when an insert happens the index needs to be updated also and that takes time

Comment: @GuidoG What happens in terms of B-tree structure of the index ?

Comment: In addition to the leaf nodes of the b-tree, the non-leaf nodes also need to be updated when page splits occur, the leaf page becomes empty, or the highest key in the leaf node changes. This is the same for both clustered and non-clustered indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any change of data on the table cause change to index. So for example you want insert data

Without index the operation will be (approx.)

```
1. insert data
```

With index the operation will be (approx.)

```
1. insert data
2. update the index
```

So you can see there are additional operation(overhead) because there is index.

Answer (score 0):

> This link isn't clear to me - I get mixed up between clustered and non-clustered indexes.

So, I am willing to explain the `clusters and non-cluster indexes`(As per my understanding),

**Match**

> table : book
>
> rows : pages
>
> row address : page number

**Pairs**

> *Non-Cluster Index = Book* and *Cluster Index = Dairy*

**Non-Cluster Index Explanation**

- The content of Book is written on flow. But it's Topics are sorted on last page (*extra page*) as topic name with concern page number.
- The actual rows are inserted. But the index column is sorted on another memory space with row address.
- If reader wants a specific topic, then who will search the topic name(*sorted list*) in index.
- If specific row is searched, then it's row number will obtained from index.
- The new topic has added after last topic. Then index need sorted with new topic. And it's page number added on index.
- As well as, the new row added as last row. Then, index has been re-order with new value and it's new row address added to the index.

**Cluster Index Explanation**

- Here pages and rows are inserted as sort order.
- If page want to add on Diary, then page is indexed as page number (DATE as per Diary). And inserted on concern place.
- If row is inserted on table, then table need reorder with new index column's value.
- On Dairy, pages are sorted. Where as table row are sorted. No need separate index for Dairy and Cluster Index Table.

---

Let me explain with help of Table:

```
create table #nonCluster (i int, name varchar(10)) 

create table #Cluster (i int, name varchar(10)) 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX #nonCluster   
    ON #noncluster(i);          -- Here Non-Cluster Index

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX #Cluster   
    ON #cluster(i);             -- Here Cluster Index

insert #nonCluster values(1,'one'),(9,'nine'),(5,'five')    -- Random data are inserted.
insert #Cluster values(1,'one'),(9,'nine'),(5,'five')       -- Random data are inserted.

select * from #nonCluster       -- Here we see the order of rows. That is un-order.
select * from #Cluster          -- Here we see the order of rows. That is order.

insert #nonCluster values(7,'seven')        -- Random data are inserted.
insert #Cluster values(7,'seven')           -- Random data are inserted.

select * from #nonCluster       -- Here we see the no change on order of rows. Rows are in how we were inserted.
select * from #Cluster          -- Here we see the sorted order of rows.

insert #nonCluster values(2,'two')
insert #Cluster values(2,'two')

select * from #nonCluster       -- Hence explained With help of order of rows.
select * from #Cluster          -- Hence explained With help of order of rows.
```